# How to disable window.onbeforeunload from <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I used `window.onbeforeunload` on my application. It's working on over page but when click on anchor link it should be disabled `<a href="abc.com">Click</a>`. Any ideas? Please share. My code is below it is not working:

```
var submitFormOkay = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (!submitFormOkay) {
        return "Don't delay your Success. Get FREE career counselling session. Fill in the details below";
    } else {
        submitFormOkay = '';
    }
}

<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>
```

Comment: you can have onclick function in which you can disable it

Answer (score 1):

You could attach a global click handler on `document.body` which, if the click passed through an `a` element, sets `submitFormOkay` to `true` (or you could use another variable to bypass the check, or just clear the handler by assigning `null` to `window.onbeforeunload`), e.g.:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "a", function() {
    submitFormOkay = true; // Or set another flag you'll check,
                           // or clear onbeforeunload entirely
});
```

---

Without jQuery (since I missed the `jquery` tag initially):

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var element;
    for (element = e.target; element != document.body; element = element.parentNode) {
        if (element.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
            submitFormOkay = true; // Or set another flag you'll check,
                                   // or clear onbeforeunload entirely
            break;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Why you are looping through each element on the document ? Can't you do this without this overhead. As per your `code` at every click event it loop through all the elements and check the element is an `anchor` or not .

Comment: @Mayank: I'm **not** looping through each element on the document. When a click occurs, when it reaches `body`, the above will look through the elements the click traversed in the z-order (typically very few, even 10 deep would be unusual -- but 1000-deep still wouldn't be a problem). Say you had a div with another div with another div with a paragraph with a span and an em in the span. You click the em. It looks at the em, span, paragraph, div, div, div -- and then stops at body. Trivial, esp. in response to a user action such as a click.

Comment: Was traversing to parent till the body really needed for the solution ?

Comment: @Mayank: This is standard event delegation. You seem to think it's inefficient or strange; it's neither. We hook up a single handler on a single element, rather than attaching a handler to every anchor element in the document. It works if new anchors are added dynamically, without having to hook handlers on those new elements. Etc.

Answer (score -2):

using jquery it can be follow:

```
var submitFormOkay = false;
$(window).on('beforeunload',function () {
    if (!submitFormOkay) {`enter code here`
        return "Don't delay your Success. Get FREE career counselling session. Fill in the details below";
    } else {
        submitFormOkay = '';
    }
})

<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.com">Click</a>
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(window).off('beforeunload');
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```